# why I am using different node runtime version in cloud function?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

[image]

as you can see at the image above, locally I am using node v10.16.3, but from cloud function dashboard it seems I still using runtime node JS 8. is this ok ? or do make something wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According tho the documentation: "You  have to set the version in the engines field in the package.json file that was created in your functions/ directory during initialization" [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions).

Please keep in mind that Node.js 10 runtime is currently in beta.

For example, to use only version 10, edit this line in package.json:

```
"engines": {"node": "10"}
```